# How do I insert lightning web component child templates and their JS files using SFDX?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

**Context**

I have a parent component in vscode.

parent.html

```
<template>
    <my-child-component></my-child-component>
</template>
```

parent.js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Parent extends LightningElement {}
```

I have a child component in different files using SFDX vscode.

myChildComponent.html

```
<template>
    <div>Hello World</div>
</template>
```

myChildComponent.js

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class Parent extends LightningElement {}
```

My vscode file structure looks like this:

```
--force-app
--|main
---|default
----|aura
----|lwc
-----|app
------|parent.html
------|parent.js
------|myChildComponent.html
------|myChildComponent.js
----|.eslintrc.json
----|jsconfig.json
```

My jsconfig.json looks like this.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "c/player": [
                "app/parent.js",
            ]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "**/*",
        "../../../../.sfdx/typings/lwc/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
}
```

**Question**

How do I add the myChildComponent into the parent component using SFDX and vscode? I have tried running the code as is above, and I have tried adding this into the jsconfig.json

```
"paths": {
            "c/player": [
                "app/parent.js",
                "app/myChildComponent.js"
            ]
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how LWC works. Each component should be in its own folder. That is, your file structure would look more like this:

```
-- force-app
--| main
---| default
----| lwc
-----| parent
------| parent.html
------| parent.js
-----| myChildComponent
------| myChildComponent.html
------| myChildComponent.js
```

Check out [the docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_source_file_format.htm) and look at an [example](https://github.com/trailheadapps/purealoe-lwc), more of which you can find on the [Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component).

Answer (score 1):

@sfdcfox gave an awesome answer/guidelines. For others who might have a similiar question I have some subtle points that I missed.

The file structure should include meta.xml files for each component.

```
-- force-app
--| main
---| default
----| lwc
-----| parent
------| parent.html
------| parent.js
------| parent.js-meta.xml
-----| myChildComponent
------| myChildComponent.html
------| myChildComponent.js
------| myChildComponent.js-meta.xml
```

The parent XML can look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="parent">
  <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
  <targets>
    <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
    <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
    <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
  </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

The myChildComponent XML can look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata" fqn="myChildComponent">
  <apiVersion>45.0</apiVersion>
  <isExposed>true</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Also, one addtional small point I found.  In the parent.html reference to myChildComponent should be wrapped in a div tag.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <c-myChildComponent></c-myChildComponent>
  </div>
</template>
```